# In Java polymorphism, can all the classes that implements an interface be created as that type interface?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, super, implements

As I proceed through my online tutorial, I came across this lesson. I have an interface and two classes that implements that interface.

```
public interface Payable {
double getPaymentAmount();
}
```

and

- class `Invoice` that implements the above interface `Payable`
- class `SalariedEmployee` that extends an abstract class `Employee` which implements `Payable` interface.
- A test class that contains the main method to test this.

Now in the test class, when creating an array of objects, the type of               object was referred to as `Payable[]` rather than `SalariedEmployee[]` or `Invoice[]`, like

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Payable[] payableObjects = new Payable[4];
    payableObjects[0] = new Invoice("0000", "abc", 1,2);
    payableObjects[1] = new SalariedEmployee("test", "user", "000-000", 35);
```

- Is this because all the classes implements the interface Payable[] ?
- If an interface is defined at the top level hierarchy, is it always possible to create objects of all the classes that implements that interface?

Comment: 1. yes, you would get a compiler error if it wasn´t the case. 2. yes, take the `List` or `Map` as example, where you should allways declare a variable as `List` or `Map` to be able to change the assgning classtype. 
Your general usecase here is, that you only want to invoke the methods provided by this specific interface.

Comment: Thank you @KevinEsche. Please post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, this is the whole point of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first question: yes, you would get a compiler error if it wasn´t the case.

for the second case, take the `List` or the `Map` as an example. Look at the following example. We declare a list but depending on the the flag, we want the this specific `List` to act different, since it represents a different class

```
public class BookList{
    List <String> list;

    public BookList(boolean flag) {
        if(flag) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            list = new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

Since we declared it just as `List` we are able to assign different type of lists that implement this `interface`. You could change the usecase of this class very simple, while you are still able to acces every method that is provided by the interface.

That´s what your array of `Payable` is doing aswell. You want to assign different types of classes into this array, which all implement this interface.

This would make it more easy, to create methods for this specific interface. Take a summing method as an example for your case.

```
public int sumPayable(Payable[] payables) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(Payable p : payables) {
        sum += p.getPaymentAmount();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

In this case, it wouldn´t matter what the actuall class of each of this classes that do implements `Payable` is, since you could simply pass an array, like you did create, to this method.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. I haven't come across this `<String>` operator yet. What is it used for, and what is it called as? If you can give me a term to look up, I would google it.

Comment: @scott these are [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Answer (score 4):

Your question title is not grammatical, but the word choice suggests there's a subtle misunderstanding of concepts going on.

You can only create a class as that class. That is, you can't write `new Payable` and somehow expect there to be any `Invoice` or `SalariedEmployee` objects being created.

But you can make a reference to a `Payable` point to any object that implements `Payable`. That's pretty much the fundamental idea of subtype polymorphism.

What's going on in the example is that an array of four `Payable` references is created. These references don't yet point at anything (they're null) and there are no `Invoice` or `SalariedEmployee` objects around yet, only the array object.

Then, the code creates two objects and assigns them to two of the references. This works the same as if the array elements were independent variables. (Almost, but the difference is due to array covariance, which isn't important at this point.) In particular, the result of the `new` operator has the type `Invoice` in the first case, not `Payable`. You can assign the `Invoice` to the `Payable` reference, but the conversion happens at assignment, not at creation.

So technically, the answer to your title question is "no, objects are always created as the type you specify in the `new` expression, but you can convert the references afterwards".